# function only runs when I type slowly

Tags: javascript, setinterval, innerhtml, getelementbyid, onkeydown

I am trying to determine how long a key is pressed when you are typing.

here is my javascript:

```
var keyDownTimer = 0;
var keyUpTimer = 0;
var keyPressedCounter = 0;
var dt;
var keyDownDisplay = document.getElementById("keyDownTimer");
var keyPressedDisplay = document.getElementById("keyPressed");
keyDownDisplay.innerHTML = keyDownTimer;
keyPressedDisplay.innerHTML = keyPressedCounter;
function keypressed(){
keyPressedCounter++;
  keyPressedDisplay.innerHTML = keyPressedCounter;
}
function keydown(){
  dt = setInterval(addDownTime, 1);
}
function addDownTime(){
  keyDownTimer++;
  keyDownDisplay.innerHTML = keyDownTimer/1000;
}
function keyup(){
  clearInterval(dt);
}
```

and my html

```
<style>
        div{
      height:25px;
      width:100px;
      display:inline-block;
      margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="keyUpTimer"></div><div id="keyDownTimer"></div><div id="keyPressed"></div>
<input id="textBox" type="text" onkeyup="keyup()" onkeydown="keydown()" onkeypress="keypressed()">
```

as I am typing in the text box, everything works correctly, but then for some reason, the keyDownTimer just starts to run, as if keydown() won't run.
I know my code is a little hard to read, but I'm pretty sure that its correct. and that it should run properly. typing slowly seems to help the problem for a little bit, but it still ends up running infinity.
Any help would be appreciated. and if you could explain why its doing what its doing, that would be great.

Comment: What happens if you press (and hold) A, then press B, then release both? This is something that happens often when typing fast... (Think about what happens to `dt` in this case!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing your dt variable, which references many intervals.

The issue is when you press multiple keys down at the same time, the first key down's dt is replaced with the second and so on.

Try this:

```
var dt = 0;
...
function keydown(){
  if(dt == 0){
    dt = setInterval(addDownTime, 1);
  }
}
function addDownTime(){
  keyDownTimer++;
  keyDownDisplay.innerHTML = keyDownTimer/1000;
}
function keyup(){
  clearInterval(dt);
  dt = 0;
}
```